# How to make sl no in FOR loop in vue page in quasar

Tags: vuejs3, quasar-framework, quasar

```
  <q-item clickable  v-for="(i, index) in myproducts" :key="i.id">
    <q-item-section>{{ index ++ }}</q-item-section>          ------------Here is error
    <q-item-section>{{ i.item }}</q-item-section>
    <q-item-section left>{{ i.barcode }}</q-item-section>
    <q-item-section>{{ i.unit }}</q-item-section>
    <q-item-section>
      <q-input
        v-model.number="myproducts[index].qty"
        type="number"
        style="max-width: 60px"
      />
    </q-item-section>

  </q-item>
```

Here is my code. I need sl no in ascending order. While using index++ i am getting error.
TIA

Comment: Just use `index`. You're already in a loop, it gets incremented automatically. A `v-for` is not a `for`. Please have a look at the [documentation](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/list.html).

Comment: It starts from 0

Comment: If you want it to start from `1` use `index + 1`. Difference is that `index++` assigns to `index` the value of `index + 1`, while `index + 1` returns the value of `index + 1` without mutating `index`. You don't want to mutate `index` in a `v-for`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that

`<q-item-section>{{ index ++ }}</q-item-section>`

will try to mutate the `index` variable, while what I believe you're trying to do is output the current index increased by 1.

To do that you should use

`<q-item-section>{{ index + 1 }}</q-item-section>`